# word vba number format (percentage)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy data from excel into word using vba codes. The values are in decimals, 0.02 or 0.04 but I would like to change it to 2% or 4%. I won't have rounding issues since the only values that are in the list is 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04 or 0.05.

Here are my codes,

```
'new line
.TypeParagraph
.Font.Size = 10.5
.TypeText Space(17)
.TypeText Format(ws2.Range("L1").Value, "#%") & Space(5) & "Inforce: " & ws12.Range("M56").Text & " (" & ws12.Range("N56").Text & ")"
```

Now the codes seem to run through, by pressing F8, but it just doesnt produce 2% or 4% instead it is still showing as 0.02 or 0.04. I tried to change .value to .text but same result. There is no error, just not the desire result I am looking for.

I am only pasting this portion of codes since the rest works fine.

[image]

Comment: I just tried to change the codes to format ("x", "Percent") but same result, still giving me 0.02.

Comment: The only one that will format to a percent sign is Format(ws2.Range("L1").Value, "#%") .  Are you looking for the other two values at the end to be formatted as percent as well?  if so you will need to surround them with the Format method

Comment: my codes aren't working so Format(ws2.Range("L1").Value, "#%") is not getting me 2% but has the default format of x.xx and such. But i m not looking for changing the remaining two to be formatted.

Comment: Format("0.03", "#%") does produce 3% as well as Format(0.03, "#%") so Maybe the issue is with ws2.Range("L1").Value  try Format(CDbl(ws2.Range("L1").Value), "#%")  also Try a Debug.Print Format(ws2.Range("L1").Value, "#%")

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just tried both. First one gives me a type dis-match error on that line of code and second one how do I see the result? It went through but i dont see the anything on my report that reflected that part of the codes.

Comment: Press Control G to get the immediate window to see the output of the Debug.

Comment: I did it but there is just a question mark, "?" in the window. Something went wrong?

Comment: I would do a Debug.Print on ws2.Range("L1").Value as I think that is where your issue is.

Comment: I did but on the debug.print its just showing a single question mark, nothing else.